# Search For String in Multidimensional Array

Tags: java

I am trying to find a contact by searching the first two names of the array below and then update the phone number associated with the contact. In the coding I've provided, I can find the first name of the contact (strFirstName) in the outer loop but can't verify that it is associated with the appropriate last name (strLastName). Even tho in the array provided there are no duplicates of first or last name, I want my coding to be able to match the exact record.

After I find the appropriate record, I the need to prompt the user for the new phone number. I believe I can figure this part, but I'm open to ideas to accomplish this.

numContacts = the numbers of rows in the array

```
    String [][] contactsArray = { 

    {"Emily","Watson","913-555-0001"},
    {"Madison","Jacobs","913-555-0002"},
    {"Joshua","Cooper","913-555-0003"},
    {"Brandon","Alexander","913-555-0004"},
    {"Emma","Miller","913-555-0005"},
    {"Daniel","Ward","913-555-0006"},
    {"Olivia","Davis","913-555-0007"},
    {"Isaac","Torres","913-555-0008"},
    {"Austin","Morris","913-555-0009"}

    public static void updateContact(Scanner scanner, String[][] contactsArray, int numContacts) {
    System.out.println("Updating contact");
    System.out.print("Enter first and last name: ");
    String strFirstName = scanner.next();
    String strLastName = scanner.next();


    for (int i=0; i < numContacts; i++){
        System.out.println(i);
         if (contactsArray[i][0].equals(strFirstName) ) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3;j++) {
                System.out.println(j);
                if (contactsArray[1][j].equals(strLastName) ) {
                    System.out.println("yes");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("no");
                    }
            }   
         }
    }
}
```

Appreciate all the help resolving this in advance.

Comment: Create a helper function `int FindContact(String firstName, String lastName)` that returns the index or `-1` if not found.

Comment: I'd suggest writing a class named `Contact` to encapsulate a `firstName`, `lastName` and `phoneNumber` into a single object, instead of an array. This would mean you can write code like `contactsArray[i].getFirstName()` instead of `contactsArray[i][0]`, which should make your code easier to understand and debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel you are close to the solution. The string comparison with the last name is unfortunately incorrect.

In fact, you are doing `contactsArray[i][0]` for firstname, which is correct. However, you are doing `contactsArray[1][j]` for the lastname, which is incorrect. Maybe `contactsArray[i][1]` is more correct.

Then you could ask yourself if you really need your second loop? You actually just want to find *a record* given the first and lastname. Therefore, you only need one loop to iterate over your "records".

Finally, you should break out of your loop if the record was actually found, and print "yes". If none was found after the loop, you should print "no".